# Having trouble with re and matching groups

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm just pulling my hair out with python regexp's.

I have a string which contains the multi-line output from an os command.

One such line will contain a string like this following:

2015/04/13.16:26:07 156.0 GB of instance data copied, dev_iosecs 1887, dev_iorate 88.8 MB/s

I am wanting to parse out "156.0 GB" into two matching groups. This field can also contain TB, MB, KB and possibly even just byes but for now I just wanna focus on TB, MB and KB and I'll deal with the potential scenario where it's just bytes later if it arises.

```
    if self.type == "cpinstance":
        if re.search("of instance data copied", line):
            m = re.match("(?P<datasize>\d[.][\d]) (?P<units>TB|GB|MB|KB) of instance data copied", line)
            print m.group('datasize'), m.group('units')
            if m.group('units') == "GB":
                print "MATCH!!!!!"
```

I've tried scores of permutations of regexps and can't for the life of me get m.group to ever work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./listInstances.py", line 187, in <module>
    tscript = OSBTranscript(image.jobid)
  File "/devel/REPO/PYLIB/osb.py", line 833, in __init__
    print m.group('datasize'), m.group('units')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I'm sure it's something stupid staring me right in the face but currently eluding me. =p

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The error message suggests that `m` is `None`, which means that `match` found no results. Just checking: are you aware that `match` has to match starting at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Well I was trying re.search at that point and still nada. Let me try that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` always starts at the beginning of the line, so it will fail when it sees the date and time section. Try using `search` instead of `match`.

```
import re

line = "2015/04/13.16:26:07 156.0 GB of instance data copied, dev_iosecs 1887, dev_iorate 88.8 MB/s"

if re.search("of instance data copied", line):
    m = re.search("(?P<datasize>\d[.][\d]) (?P<units>TB|GB|MB|KB) of instance data copied", line)
    print m.group('datasize'), m.group('units')
    if m.group('units') == "GB":
        print "MATCH!!!!!"
```

Result:

```
6.0 GB
MATCH!!!!!
```

Good start, but it only matches one digit before the decimal point. try putting a star after your `\d`. (or perhaps a plus, depending on whether you want to find numbers like ".5".)

```
import re

line = "2015/04/13.16:26:07 156.0 GB of instance data copied, dev_iosecs 1887, dev_iorate 88.8 MB/s"

if re.search("of instance data copied", line):
    m = re.search("(?P<datasize>\d*[.][\d]) (?P<units>TB|GB|MB|KB) of instance data copied", line)
    print m.group('datasize'), m.group('units')
    if m.group('units') == "GB":
        print "MATCH!!!!!"
```

Result:

```
156.0 GB
MATCH!!!!!
```

Comment: Ok, yea I needed to use star and not plus. I had a version where I was using plus instead and wasn't working. This is working with star now. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

[`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches from the beginning of the string, you need to use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) which looks for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match ...

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '2015/04/13.16:26:07 156.0 GB of instance data copied, dev_iosecs 1887, dev_iorate 88.8 MB/s'
>>> m = re.search(r'(?P<datasize>\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (?P<units>[TGMK]B)', s)
>>> print m.group('datasize'), m.group('units')

156.0 GB
```

**Note:** Your regular expression inside of the `<datasize>` named group was not matching as expected. You needed a quantifier to catch the entire pattern, so I modified it to allow for that as well.